# idiomatic English phrase for 'intuitive operation'

Tags: phrase-request

I have a new microwave. There are many commercial stickers on it advertising this newly-made model. Here is rough translation into English of some of the phrases from those stickers:

- 5 modes of temperature
- increased safety
- new de-freezing mode
- easier way of food-retrieving
- renewed overall exterior
- intuitive operation

I wonder what the right way of expressing the last thought in English would be. What is meant by 'intuitive operation' there is the fact that this new model of microwave has a better system of symbols drawn next to each button, so it is very clear how to use it and you can easily guess by those symbols how to operate it even if you don't know the language.

So, what phrase in English would usually be used in such case?

Comment: "intuitive operation" sounds fine to me, as a short phrase on a sticker.

Comment: Yes, seems OK to me - or perhaps 'clear symbols'? BTW, _defrosting_ is the usual term for thawing frozen food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Intuitive operation" is good, and indeed here is an [advert for a coffee maker](https://uk.jura.com/en/purchasing-advice/weshalb-jura/intuitive-bedienung) with "intuitive operation" that prepares speciality coffees at the touch of a button.

As Kate notes "defrosting", not de-freezing, the compound "food-retrieving" is odd, and I'm not sure what "modes of temperature" really means, but a lot of advertising schtick doesn't make much sense when you analyse it.

Comment: "Modes of temperature" might be power levels.